# Sum 3 Tables and Subtract the User Request

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello Developers/Programmers

I am working on withdrawal function on my website.

So it goes like this

I need to total the 3 tables i have by User ID with status of '1' ,and Subtract the Inputed amount by the User Requested the Withdrawal

These are my 3 tables

```
tbl_bonus_1
id | amount | user_id | status
1      20         1        1
2      20         1        1
3      20         3        1

tbl_bonus_2
id | amount | user_id | status
1      30         1        1
2      30         1        1
3      30         3        1

tbl_bonus_3
id | amount | user_id | status
1      40         1        1
2      40         1        1
3      40         3        1
```

Now I need to get all that 3 tables by USER ID and get the total of it.
After getting the total i need to subtract the Inputted quantity of the USER
and update the status to 0 so that the user cant withdraw again.

Im using Codeigniter 3.1.5

Comment: Here's a thought: don't have 3 tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, sum(amount)
from 
(select * from tbl_bonus_1
union
select * from tbl_bonus_2
union
select * from tbl_bonus_3) tt
where status = 1
group by user_id
```

DEMO:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f1807e/1

And UPDATE (single user):

```
UPDATE tbl_bonus_1 t1 INNER JOIN tbl_bonus_2 t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_bonus_3 t3
ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
SET t1.amount = 0, t2.amount = 0, t3.amount = 0
WHERE t1.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: i'll take a look at this get back with a response shortly

Comment: what is the user inputted the amount of 150 and he/she has 160 total bonus is the update will not affect the remaining 10 balance?

Comment: Здесь баланс сбрасывается, ноль должен быть заменен балансом SET t1.amount = 0, t2.amount = 0, t3.amount = 0

Comment: i dont understand  
Здесь баланс сбрасывается, ноль должен быть заменен балансом please use english

Comment: In this line of code, the amount is set to zero.
If you want to leave the remainder, you need to specify it instead of zero.

Comment: example: SET t1.amount = 10, t2.amount = 0, t3.amount = 0

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, you don't want to subtract from these tables if you want to manage a balance. You need to add a 4th table that is withdrawal amount, so you can capture the transactions. If you have a total of 160 across 3 tables, and the user withdrawals 150, how would you determine which to decrement.

I would suggest actually consolidating all of these into 1 trasaction table, and capture the amounts there.

So to get what you need you will need to leverage variables which will need to be passed to the query.  Below will give you what you are asking for.  That being said, this is not the correct way to do this.  Also, there is no way to determine which of the 3 balances you want to subtract the withdraw from.  This is just not how transaction ledgers work and for a lot of reasons I am not going to get in to right now.  At the bottom of this answer is how I suggest you should build your table.  You will be able to get information with more easy while capturing more/better data.

**How to get data from current structure:**

```
set @withdraw = 150.00, @user = 1;

select user_id, sum(amount) as prevBalance
, @remainingBalance := if(@user = user_id,sum(amount)-@withdraw,sum(amount)) as remainingBalance
from 
(select * from tbl_bonus_1
union
select * from tbl_bonus_2
union
select * from tbl_bonus_3) balance
group by user_id;
```

**How you should build your schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE ledger (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
                   ,user_id int
                   , amount decimal(5,2)
                   , transaction_type varchar(20)
                   ,PRIMARY KEY (ID));
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES
(null,1,20,'Bonus1'),
(null,1,20,'Bonus1'),
(null,3,20,'Bonus1'),

(null,1,30,'Bonus2'),
(null,1,30,'Bonus2'),
(null,3,30,'Bonus2'),

(null,1,40,'Bonus3'),
(null,1,40,'Bonus3'),
(null,3,40,'Bonus3'),

(null,1,-150,'Withdraw')
```

;

Then all you would need to do is run the following query.

```
select user_id, sum(amount) balance from ledger
group by user_id;
```

Comment: It's not what I'd do. I'd have a single table of transactions

Comment: Well I agree, what he really needs is 1 transaction table. Effectively a ledger. But assuming he already has logic built around his existing schema, I would suggest separating the transactions.

Comment: @beautiful.drifter can you provide sample query?

Comment: @KonjeshEsbrading see answer